# Validating a Calculated field in Acrobat using Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, acrobat

I am creating a form that calculates a weighted fee. The form basically multiplies an allocation percentage by a predefined annual-percentage fee to figure out the weighted average fee. I am trying to figure out the best way to insure that the user of the form makes the allocation add to 100%. Right now my code looks like this:

```
    var FeeTotal = (this.getField("dvisors Fee annum1").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Feeannum2").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum3").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum4").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum5").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum6").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum7").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum8").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum9").value 
    + this.getField("dvisors Fee annum10").value);

    var total = (this.getField("Manager%1").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%2").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%3").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%4").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%5").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%6").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%7").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%8").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%9").value 
    + this.getField("Manager%10").value);

    if (total=1) {
        event.value = FeeTotal;
        this.field.fontcolor("red");
    } else {
        event.value = FeeTotal;
        this.field.fontcolor("Black")
    }
```

The idea is that the field that this script is calculating a value for will have red text if the allocation percentage doesn't add to 100%. I don't want to use app.alert because the users of this form will change the allocation percentages quite often and the constant alerts would be cumbersome.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are operating with percentages here, the end result will in a number of cases most likely _not exactly_ equal one. (Go research what problems there are with floating point arithmetics if you don’t know why.) So it might be advisable to allow for a very small tolerance in the comparison.

Comment: Ok, Do you know why the existing code doesn't work properly? Even if I test it with exactly 100% it doesn't change the text color like I want it to. Thanks

Comment: Well first of all, the comparison operator in JavaScript is _not_ `=` …

Comment: What should I do to make it work? I changed the comparison operator ==, my mistake.

Comment: First of all you should confirm if what you are assuming is actually true, that `total` _is_ `==1` – use `app.alert` for that as a temporary debugging measure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what was discussed here, in Acrobat 7 pro this works:

```
this.getField("thisfield").value = 
this.getField("field1").value +
this.getField("field2").value;

var total = (this.getField("thisfield").value);

var total2 = (this.getField("anothercalculatedtotalfield").value);

if (total2==(this.getField("thisfield").value)) {
    event.value = total;
    this.getField("thisfield").textColor = color.black;
} else {
    event.value = total;
    this.getField("thisfield").textColor = color.red;
}
```